# Adding a wp_head hook from an included PHP file

Tags: themes, hooks, include, wp-head

I am using a [WordPress plugin for including PHP code within posts and pages](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/allow-php-in-posts-and-pages/), and it's working great - however, I need to insert some styles and scripts, and in order to do that, I need to add a hook to wp_head. I tried it, creating a function and using `add_action('wp_head','my_func');` but it didn't work - my stuff is not being included.

I think its because wp_head is being called before my script it being included.

I would like to do this without changing any of my themes files.

Is there any way to do this? I am using the latest WordPress version.

Comment: Are you trying to add the hook within a post? That won't work. Hooks must be placed inside your theme's `functions.php` file.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was trying. WP hooks only work inside the Functions file?

Comment: How would one go about adding scripts and styles to the head tag from a specific page then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enqueue styles and scripts properly, use the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action like so:

```
function wpa_63708_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'my-script','/path/to/script' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script' );
}    

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpa_63708_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Comment: Use wp_enqueue_style for stylesheets, but on the same wp_enqueue_scripts action hook.